# How to target @import inside an external CSS file loaded with <link> tag using JS or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, optimization

I'm using a third party JS library that loads **minified CSS assets** by appending a **link** HTML tag to the **head**.

Inside of that CSS file there are few **@import** (at-rules) that imports an old version of font awesome which overrides the one I have.
How can I remove that **@import** rule?

I've tried to use

```
var styleTag = document.querySelector('link[href="https://external_file.css"]')

var sheet = styleTag.sheet ? styleTag.sheet : styleTag.styleSheet;

sheet.deleteRule (2); //the @import I want to delete is the third rule in the css document
```

however that code disables few more CSS rules in that document probably because it's minified

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but you can try this approach.

Include your css properties in a separate file. Let application first load the minified css. Then load your css files.

For example
**first.css**

```
#something{
  color: #FFF;
 }

And then in the second file:

 #something{
  color: #000;
 }
```

In this case `background-color` from second file will be applied

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this would work in normal situations, however in my case the CSS file is being requested after the page has fully loaded so that CSS would always take priority.